# Is it possible to see a user page for a deleted account?

Tags: feature-request

I have just noticed that a particular user has deleted his account.

This user had exceptional quality in his answers, to the point that I sometimes just scrolled through his answers for random things to learn.  Now that the account has been deleted, I can't find any place to query for the list of answers associated with user3389.

I don't know exactly what the philosophy behind account deletion rules is.  Would such a feature work?

Comment: No, you cannot see the account page anymore, the association with the answers is gone.

Comment: What Stack Exchange site is this on?

Comment: Whew - it's not Eric Lippert...

Comment: gaming.stackexchange, and to be clear I'm only interested in the user as a grouping of interesting answers.  I'm not looking for the personal info at all.

Comment: @Tugs - I think it's clear you have no ill intentions, but what you want will not be possible.  When a user deletes his account, the expectation is that you *can't* look over all their contributions anymore.  Grouping together their contributions in one place would run against that.

Comment: @tugs Does my answer not solve your question?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I [composed this data.stackexchange query](https://data.stackexchange.com/gaming/revision/102918/124756/deleted-user-question-answer-look-up), which should find you what you've been looking for.

Answer (score 3):

Since you know the user's name, you can still search for the user's answers with Google:

https://www.google.com/search?q=site%3Agaming.stackexchange.com+user3389

A regular search: [user:user3389 is:answer](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/search?q=user%3Auser3389+is%3Aanswer) returns 0 results for a deleted user.

Comment: Hmm, if that is the actual user, his account has not been deleted. Are we talking SO here?

Comment: user3389 was from his gaming.stackexchange account, I guess the user number would be different for each SE site?

Comment: @tugs: Yes, usernumbers do not correlate.

Comment: The stackexchange search doesn't work: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/search?q=user:user3389

Comment: @tugs, Nope, it doesn't.  I'd assumed you meant SO and saw results there.  Updated.

Comment: I know who that person is, but they obviously deleted it because they wanted to be gone. Not sure posting workarounds is of any help (your search link is incorrect anyway), but one can only expect so much privacy in today's digital age.